# Google contacts not syncing

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, google-contacts

I have a **Lenovo A6020a40** with **Android 5.1.1**.
Local GMail contacts and cloud ones have always been in sync till some day ago.
Then, suddenly, without any modification on my phone and/or on the cloud, sync stopped working.
I realized something was wrong when I created some new contact on the cloud and I didn't find it on my phone.
Then I created a new local contact and there's no way I can see it on the cloud

Naturally I've gone to **Settings > Accounts > Google > Gmail** and checked **Contacts sync** is on; I've also tried to turn it off and the on again, but nothing changed: after a sync attempt I have 778 local contacts and 777 cloud ones.

I've also tried **Contacts Sync Fix** app (as suggested on some forum), but app says none of my 778 contacts are having problems.

I'm out of ideas...

**--- EDITED ---**
After a few days and some brand new account created on my phone (and saved in my GMAIL profile according to my phone), GMail contacts are still 777.

**--- EDITED ---**
Contacts are not in sync anymore, even if everytime I change something I see my phone trying to sync.
If I change/add something on the cloud contacts, modification is not sent to my phone and vice-versa.
Note that emails and calendar are synchronized properly!

Comment: Just to be sure - your contacts app on mobile shows that the contact is sitting on the Google account, and not local, correct?

Comment: @arieljannai: that's correct!

Comment: http://www.droidforums.net/threads/when-does-google-sync-contacts.14278/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove that account and again add it in your account. Then it will again sync all your contacts to your Gmail.

Comment: Sure, but all the contacts I've added and/or edited on my phone (even if they are part of the gmail account on the phone) will be lost in that case. This is the last attempt I'm going through...

Comment: I dont think so, only those contact that are saved in Gmail will be lost, not the local one's

Comment: Contacts saved in Gmail account on the phone and not synced with cloud will be lost if I remove Google account from phone, that's for sure!

Comment: If you are scared of your contacts you can simply take a backup of them. As I think that contacts stored locally are in Android storage and have no link with Google accounts and contacts in the accounts will get affevted after removal of that account.

Comment: Sure I could, but it's not a solution, it's a workaround and not the fastest one: I should backup GMail accounts on my phone on another account (Microsoft, local, whatever), delete GMail account, restore GMail account, wait for it to be in sync with cloud, then push local contacts back on GMail account and finally remove duplicates. Finally I can't be sure changed contacts on phone won't be in conflict with cloud ones. I will go through this pain only if it's the last chance I have honestly...